# How to pass NSManagedObject to userInfo of UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uilocalnotification, nsnotification

I'm trying to pass an NSManagedObject to userInfo of UILocalNotification, something like:

```
NSManagedObject *obj = ...;

UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
localNotification.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:obj, @"KeyName", nil];
```

but it crashed with below error

> Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType')
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unable to serialize userInfo: (null)'

To my understanding, the root cause is that NSManagedObject is not serializable, so how to fix this issue? any workaround here?

I have also tried NSManagedObjectID, and got same error here.

Comment: Please show here ...... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637179/uilocalnotification-crash

Comment: Thanks @Rohitsuvagiya, I do know the root cause, and I'd like to ask the solution here.